# Restarting nginx keeps asking PEM pass phrase

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to reload nginx, I have a wildcard certificate for one domain which I got from namecheap, now I have moved it to my server, and assigned a nginx configuration rule with this:

```
ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/certs/website.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/certs/website.com.key;
ssl_ciphers                 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!EDH;
add_header                  Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
```

Now when I reload nginx by doing `service nginx reload`, I keep getting this prompted:

> Reloading nginx configuration: Enter PEM pass phrase:

Unfortunately, I don't know the PEM pass phrase, but I do have the pass phrase when I generated the CSR with OpenSSL, but this did not match the PEM pass phrase.

I have no idea what I can do, how can I recover this, or be able to remove it (if it does not affect the security)

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and nginx 1.2.6.

Answer (score 8):

Try just press enter:)

But, seriously,  If you'll know the passphrase you can remove it:

```
openssl rsa -in website.com.key_secure.key -out website.com.key
```

Comment: (And regenerate the certificate if you aren't sure of what the password is.  It should be the password used when you created the private key.)